# How to install mintty into 'Git Bash' on windows?

Tags: windows, git, git-bash

I have installed git on windows from http://git-scm.com/download/win and I use the **Git Bash** shortcut to access git commands.

Unfortunately, **Git Bash** uses the Windows Command (CMD.EXE) Terminal which is horrible to work with.

How can I change **Git Bash** to use mintty instead of CMD.EXE?

Comment: Note that the installers for current releases from git-scm include an option to use mintty OR cmd as the terminal

Comment: For a long time now git-scm has installed a much nicer Terminal.  For example, now you can resize it horizontally.

Answer (score 9):

Head over to http://code.google.com/p/mintty/ and download the latest zip file containing the mintty msys package.  As of 18 Oct 2014, the latest version is **mintty-1.1.3-msys.zip**

Extract `mintty.exe` from the zip file and copy it to the `bin` folder where you installed git.  If you installed git to the default location, the path is `C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin`

Next right click on the windows shortcut for **Git Bash**.  Change the target to: `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\mintty.exe" /bin/sh --login -i`.  If you installed git to a different location, you will need to use your installed path.

Now clicking on the **Git Bash** shortcut should open mintty.

Comment: I tried this approach. Modifying the Git Bash shortcut worked and that opens a Mintty terminal, but modifying `C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\Git Bash.vbs` by copying and pasting your version has not modified the behaviour of Git Bash within the context menu - Git Bash still opens with cmd.exe in this case: http://puu.sh/ddSW0/5efa2f5c42.png http://puu.sh/ddSWG/91e68d1790.jpg

Comment: Apologies - that part of the instructions were provided by another stackoverflow user so I have removed them.

Comment: No problem, going through the Git Bash shortcut suffices for now and being able to use Mintty more than makes up for the trouble, cheers.

Comment: That Google code archive is really out of date! Please update your comment.

Answer (score 4):

Since 2017 the most elegant solution is wsltty from the developer of mintty. It's [mintty as a terminal for Bash on Ubuntu on Windows / WSL](https://github.com/mintty/wsltty).

Just download and execute the [installer](https://github.com/mintty/wsltty/releases).

Answer (score 4):

Try reinstall git and:

1. Uncheck "Only show new options"
2. Choose "Use MinTTY" instead of the default one

[image]

Comment: This was useful for me as I noticed the root cause of having two different versions of git bash on 2 different systems