# bash in windows 10 (anniversary update) keeps adding characters to command line

Tags: linux, windows-10, command-line, bash, ssh

I've managed to set myself up such that i can launch bash from my command window in windows 10.  It's pretty cool!  The only problem is that when I ssh into a remote linux box and run different commands, the prompt is always followed by some extra characters... like so:

```
remote_linux1:/var/www/mywebapp/cgi-bin# cd ..
remote_linux1:/var/www/mywebapp# 30;46R
```

Notice the "30;46R" at the end of the command prompt above...

or when i ssh into remote_linux1 in the first place, this is what happens:

```
root@CA2UA5232QPZ:/mnt/c/Users/me# ssh root@remote_linux1.uua.int.net   
 18:42:03 up 23 days, 23:14,  load average: 0.06, 0.13, 0.13
remote_linux1:~# 17;29R
```

This only happens on remote machines that I've ssh'd into using my bash command tool.  What are these characters and how do i get rid of them? 
Thanks.

Comment: probably terminal control codes that the remote is sending that the host terminal emulator isn't handling. theoretically either remote or host could be reconfigured to handle them.  [MinTTY has a WSL installer](https://github.com/mintty/wsltty/releases) and may be more friendly.  see also [this bash+MinTTY question](http://superuser.com/questions/1110045/windows-10-bash-and-mintty) and [this WSL issue on github](https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/279) (and check for similar terminal/console-related issues).